# Write file if not existing

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, inputstream

I am trying to create a block that writes a file when the file doesn't exsist, but it has turned into a Catch-22. The file doesn't exist, so it can't write the file so it can exsist. Here is my attempt:

```
if(!FileReadWrite.file2.exists())
        FileReadWrite.fileWrite();

public static File file2 = new File("./settings.txt");

public static void fileWrite()
{
    try
    {
         FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file2);
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
         String c = Byte.toString(Textures.a);
         out.write(c);
         out.close();
     }catch (Exception e)
     {
         System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
     }
    int ch;
    StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
    InputStream fin = null;
    try
    {
        fin = new FileInputStream(file2);
        while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1)
        {
            strContent.append((char) ch);
        }
    fin.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using Eclipse. The file is in the bin folder, but when I export it to a jar it is outside the jar folder.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at srcD.Main.<init>(Main.java:19) //(FileReadWrite.fileWrite())
at srcD.Main.main(Main.java:129) //(Make JFrame)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at srcD.FileReadWrite.<clinit>(FileReadWrite.java:7) //(public file...)
... 2 more
```

Comment: You need to execute the jar with a user that has privileges to create files in the folder the jar locates.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have those privileges.

Comment: The first block is Main 19, the public static File line is FileReadWrite 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("settings.txt")` code returns null and `.getFile()` gets an `NPE`

---

Answer to comment

Firstly you should understand that method `getSystemResource` NOT for outside resources [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource%28java.lang.String%29)
For load outside resources from jar you have to use full path to resource, full != absolute, 
how to find full path

```
start point + path to resource
```

For example we have next files structure `/Users/fakeuser/tetsproject/` - this folder contains your jar and `conf` folder contains or should contain `settings.txt`, if you have delivery structure like this your code will be

```
 public static File file2 = new File("./conf/settings.txt");
```

And that is all.

Comment: Without the Stacktrace it is very hard to find the error. Nice catch by the way.

Comment: You are correct. How do I fix it though? There is no other way I know to load a file outside of a jar, and I have to include .getFile().

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Why not, it was one part of code without try{}catch blocks and with long initialization structure.

Comment: @Coupon22 look to second part of my answer.

Comment: The ./ solved my answer (Along with some proofreading). Thank You!